# How can I extract lat/long from GDB file in FME?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, fme-form

I have a large GDB database of points of interest across the world. I can open this up in FME and the data viewer works great in showing me the content in a way that is easily consumable. Despite all of these data rows being filled with lots of info, and being properly mapped in the world viewer feature, I don't have the lat/long coordinates for these places.

I've tried several variations of Transformations, but I am unable to output the lat/long coordinates that I am looking for. Right now I am using a coordinateExtractor, that is successfully adding new X and Y values to the output file, but the coordinates don't show up as valid on Google maps. For example, this is what I am currently getting for a given row:

```
X: 1136921.462499998509884
Y: 216469.213800000026822
```

I feel like I am close! But I am stuck. How can I get the lat/long coordinates for each of these rows in a format that Google Maps will take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Method 1*: Add a [reprojector](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/reprojector.htm) before the coordinate extractor to convert the points from the source coordinate system into **LL84**.  The points will then be in latitude/longitude.
Note that following the [coordinateExtractor](https://www.safe.com/transformers/coordinate-extractor/) the X attribute will hold longitude and the Y attribute will hold latitude.

This method assumes the GDB has the current [map projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) for the data correctly assigned; if not - use a [CoordinateSystemSetter](https://www.safe.com/transformers/coordinate-system-setter/) before the reprojector.

*Method 2*: Alternatively, use the [AttributeReprojector](https://www.safe.com/transformers/attribute-reprojector/) transformer which can be used to convert the X and Y attributes themselves into lat/lon.  This way the features themselves are unchanged.  You will need to specify the source and target coordinate systems.

Comment: thanks for your answer! That helped me get the coordinates into a format Google Maps would take. As I am going through and testing a few of them, it looks like they are pretty accurate. Some of them are slightly off, maybe within a half mile of accuracy. Is it possible that the option I used (method 1 above) is to blame? Or is this likely a limitation of the accuracy of the actual data in the GDB file?

Comment: Hard to confirm without further information.  However if most of the processed points are indeed OK - then it is fairly reasonable to assume the remaining inaccuracies is due to source data outliers.